# Adding UIImageView dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app am using UIImageViews which i want to create dynamically by using a for loop with names as imageView0,imageView1,imageView2.......

My code is as follows

```
 for(i=0;i<number;i++)
{

        scrollViewImageToDrag = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
//        NSString *imageViewnameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"scrollViewImageToDrag%d",i];

}
```

After executing for loop it should create number(example 10) of times UIImageViews with series names like imageView0,imageView1,imageView2.......

How can i achieve this.

Comment: @AlexTerente `[UIImageView new]` is the same as `[[UIImageView alloc] init]`

Comment: Only _title_ and _way of describing question_ is changed. Basic question is still the same

Comment: But of you call init on UIImageView is not properly initialized. I see that you have edited the code and you found in the docs the – initWithImage: method

Comment: You're gonna have to use NSMutableArray or something similiar. The way you want to do it simply won't work.

Answer (score 4):

when you create the UIImageView.. set them tags from  in a range say (10---20 )

so .
initialize your ImageView like this..

```
 for (int i=0; i< 20; i++) {

UIImageView *ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init] ;
// ImageView formatting code here...

ImageView.tag = i+20;
   }
```

then later when you want to have the above loop(which you gave in your question) get your UIImageView like this..

```
for (int i=0; i< 20; i++) {

UIImageView *ImageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:i+20]; // get the ImageView with tag
}
```

this is the solution ..
**You can't rename text to a variable and use its functions**

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve what you want but if you want to differentiate imageviews you can use tag property.

```
for (int i=0; i<[getEffectsImageData count]; i++)
{
    //Your code here.....

    imageViewsArray.tag = i ;// This would become your first image. and you can differentiate from tag.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike many interpreter languages in Objective-C you cannot create object names dynamically as you suggest. You may use an array instead.

```
NSMutableArray scrollViewImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:number];
 for(i=0;i<number;i++)
{
UIImageView *myNewImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[myImageView retain]; //With ARC you would not need this statement, you directly call this
myImageView.tag = i; //This may come handy to identify the images if you to not want to use
                     //or do not need to. In a table view controller you may not need that array for images in a table cell. 
[scrollViewImagesArray addObject:myNewImageView];

}
```

// later, when you do not need the images any more, to not forget to remove all objects and release the aray (unless you use ARC then nil assigning to the array should do).

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSInteger x = y = 5;
 for(NSInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
    UIImage *image = [UIIimage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageView%d",i]];
    UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc] init];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,45,45)];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [imageView setTag:i];
    [yourScrollView addSubView:imageView];

    //If you want to access your ImageView by tapping

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelect:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired=1;

    [imageView addGestureViewRecognizer:singleTap];
    image=nil;

    if(i%4==0) {
      x=0;
      y=y+50;
    } else {
     x=x+50;
   }
 }

 - (IBAction)imageSelect:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
       UIImageView *imageView=(UIImageView *)sender.view;
      //Here you can access above imageView
}
```

Good luck!